# How to call inherited method of superclass from the overridden subclass method?

Tags: java

I have a class **shape** that has a toString() method. I have another class **circle** that extends shape. This **circle** class overrides the inherited toString() method. What I want to do is call the superclass - **shape's** toString() method from **inside** the **circle's** toString() method. The following is what I have done as of now. I thought calling toString() in the toString() of the **circle** might invoke the inherited toString() but that just goes into an infinite loop.

Shape class:

```
class shape{
String color;
boolean filled;
shape()
{
    color = "green";
    filled = true;
}
shape(String color, boolean fill)
{
    this.color = color;
    this.filled = fill;
}
public String toString()
{
    String str = "A Shape with color = " + color + " and filled = " + filled + " .";
    return str;
}
}
```

Circle class:

```
class circle extends shape
{
double radius;
circle()
{
    this.radius = 1.0;
}
public String toString()
{
    String str = "A circle with radius " + radius + " and which is a subclass of " + toString();
    return str;
}
```

Please Help!

Comment: You're looking for `super.toString();`

Comment: You need to use 'super' keyword here

Comment: try `String str = "A circle with radius " + radius + " and which is a subclass of " + super.toString();`

Comment: Your code examples don't compile. When asking for help, it's best to present something clear, concise, and (where code is involved) syntactically-correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use `super.`:

```
// In Circle
public String toString() {
    String shapeString = super.toString();
    // ...
    return /*...*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call super.toString() inside the overriding method.

Comment: Thank you for your help!